# Facebook asks user to log in even though they're already logged in

Tags: facebook

I'm having a hard time getting the Facebook JS API to work as described in http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

Specifically, the user seems to get asked to log in even if they are already logged in to Facebook. For this I'm doing the following:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '3120012412', // App ID goes here
      channelURL : '//WWW.qy.ORG/channel.php', // Channel File
      status     : true, // check login status
      cookie     : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
      oauth      : true, // enable OAuth 2.0
      xfbml      : true  // parse XFBML
    });

    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.login(function(response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
       alert('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
       FB.api('/me', function(response) {
       alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
       alert('response' + response);

       FB.logout(function(response) {
         alert('Logged out.');
       });
     });
    } else {
      alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
   }
 }, {scope: 'email'});
  };

  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
  (function(d){
     var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
     d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
   }(document));
</script>
```

I also tried:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
   if (response.authResponse) {
     // logged in and connected user, someone you know
   } else {
     // no user session available, someone you dont know
   }
});
```

This also fails even when I'm already logged in to Facebook.

What should I do if I want the user to go through the minimum hassle, for just basic access to public information?  I understand they have to authorize the basic access, but it shouldn't ask them repeatedly should it?

Answer (score 0):

Your first code chunk is logging the user in, then immediately logging them out again - so you probably aren't logged in if you have been running this a few times. Remove the `FB.logout` block and try it again to see if it makes a difference.

Another thing to remember (and probably the reason your second example isnt working) is although you are logged into facebook.com, you have to be logged in to your own domain via `FB.login`. `getLoginStatus` will check for your fbsr_ cookie and consider you logged in if it is there, but you must already have the cookie, from calling `FB.login` first.

So I suggest using this:

```
    // Additional initialization code here
    FB.login(function(response) {
       if (response.authResponse) {
          alert('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
          FB.api('/me', function(response) {
             alert('Good to see you, ' + response.name + '.');
             alert('response' + response);
          });
       } else {
          alert('User cancelled login or did not fully authorize.');
       }
    }, {scope: 'email'});
```

Comment: Has this solved your problem? Please accept the answer if it has, or leave more information if it hasn't. :)